# ssh to deploy machine and running python file gives error not found even if it exists

Tags: docker, gitlab, ssh-keys, gitlab-ci-runner

I have changed the password of the user(lets call him staging_user) gitlab-runner will use to log in to a different machine that runs staging server,

and in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
staging_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    SSH_EXEC: "ssh staging_user@staging_server"
    DEPLOY_PATH: "/home/staging_user/project_site"
  only:
    - staging
  script:
    - ${SSH_EXEC} "if [ -d ${DEPLOY_PATH} ]; then \rm -r ${DEPLOY_PATH}/*; else mkdir -p ${DEPLOY_PATH}; fi"
    - echo -e ${GITSSHKEY} > conf/.ssh/id_rsa
    - scp -r * staging-user@staging_server://home/staging_user/project_site/
    - ${SSH_EXEC} "cd ${DEPLOY_PATH}/; docker-compose build --no-cache --force-rm; docker-compose up -d"
    - ${SSH_EXEC} "docker exec website_staging python /var/www/website.com/src/manage.py collectstatic --no-input"
```

the gitlab-runner runs on git01 machine and from there gitlab-runner ssh to staging_server user is staging_user (see SSH_EXEC value above)

I have noticed the `GITSSHKEY` is variable stored on the gitlab project under: `gitlab.com/test_group/project_site/settings/ci_cd` . So I believe need to update this SSH key, but I am bit confused and not sure where to run ssh-keygen to generate a new key and paste here, whether I run ssh-keygen on git01 from where gitlab-runner is ssh'ing or on `staging_server` machine.

I am getting this **error**:

```
Service 'web' failed to build: error pulling image configuration: Get https://dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/0a/0a2bad7da9b55f3121f0829de061f002ef059717fc2ed23c135443081200000e/data?Expires=1526503430&Signature=LZNRPPcqYzFoeE94jHgdxyN7gONaewh3ZF2688IVPhrOFKt-DB20gcSZIytqiDff8Hk7CS60SFKoROkU4VWMroByNqAcrFeMJGEAG-GKSSLXKPqQUsxYeXyW5rRGGbC8CqARQKsj1GBR-fTvRstcrnfhQVrn9gv~IFtqRXNB-LM_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJECH5M7VWIS5YZ6Q: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
website_web_1 is up-to-date
$ ${SSH_EXEC} "ls -lh /var/www/website.com/src/manage.py"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 staging_user staging_user 280 May 15 16:26 /var/www/website.com/src/manage.py
$ ${SSH_EXEC} "docker exec website_web_1 python /var/www/website.com/src/manage.py collectstatic --no-input"
python: can't open file '/var/www/website.com/src/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note regarding the initial question: changing the password should not impact an ssh key, since it relies on the public key being on the remote server `~staging_user/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Generating a new ssh key is needed on the source machine (the one which will initiate the ssh to the remote machine), and you would need to deploy the public key first to the remote `~staging_user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

After discussion, the [OP Ciasto piekarz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3311276/ciasto-piekarz) states [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362234/ssh-to-deploy-machine-and-running-python-file-gives-error-not-found-even-if-it-e/50362637?noredirect=1#comment87786032_50362637):

> I have discovered that if the container is already running then we get this error, but if we stop the running container and update the branch for gitlab-runner to run the pipeline then the deployment goes successful

Comment: yes that make sense, all the time I was thinking about it. so  I changed password only of the `staging_user`.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Yes, but again, changer a user password has no impact on ssh keys. A private SSH key might be protected by a passphrase, but this is unrelated to a user account password.

Comment: so at this line :  `${SSH_EXEC} "docker exec website_staging python /var/www/website.com/src/manage.py collectstatic --no-input"` does that mean gitlab_runner ssh to staging_server as staging_user then try to run `manage.py` ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz `ssh staging_user@staging_server` means: connect to `staging_server` as `staging_user`, then run any command which follows on that remote server `staging_server`.

Comment: Since I am getting the error file not found it means ssh is not authenticating user.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Which error? (you can edit your question). Start wit a simple: `${SSH_EXEC} id -a` to check that the connection goes through.

Comment: well, I think I was wrong, from machine running gitlab-runner I ran `ssh staging_user@staging_server` .with  "ls -lh /home/" -a and I got listing of staging server , except it prompts for password everytime,

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz That is the part which needs resolution first: "except it prompts for password everytime": that means the public key is not found on the remote server side, and ssh defaults back to the username/password.

Comment: the gitlab-runner public key the content of id_rsa.pub on git machine also exists on staging server machine's `authorizedkeys` file. but this `authorizedkeys` contains a public key of its own machine as well. Also since the previous steps ssh is executing and listing the contents of staging server directory ; see the result of `$ ${SSH_EXEC} "ls -lh /var/www/website.com/src/manage.py"` in my updated opening post . I think authenitcating is not the problem but now this is even more confusing.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz OK, so can you do through ssh a `docker inspect bfxpletoolssite_web_1`: the idea is to check for volume which should have been mouted but could be missing, explaining why `/var/www/website.com/src/manage.py` is missing.

Comment: I have discovered that if the container is already running then we get this error, but if we stop the running container and update the branch for gitlab-runner to run the pipeline then the deployment goes successful

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz OK. I have included your comment in the answer (in progress) for more visibility. That reminds me of https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2658. Maybe stopping an environment (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments.html#stopping-an-environment) is needed.